# Jquery ajax in loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

I am writing a Sql convertor which handles mysql to mongodb. I am writing an interface to my converter with ajax.

Ajax is handling huge convertions. This put limit to mysql select code and make convertions parted by 1000 at a time.

my code is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
<!--Start JQuery Ajax Requests-->
var pages;
var type;
$("input").click(function(event) {
    pages = $(this).attr("icr");
    type = $(this).attr("id");
    runRequest(0);
});

function runRequest(num){

    if (num > 3){
    $("#console").append("Finish!!!");
    return;
    }

    $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "#",
    async: false,
    data: "type="+type+"&page="+num*1000,
    success: function(msg){
        $("#console").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
        {
            $("#console").append(msg);
            runRequest(num+1);
        });
    }
    });
}
});
```

this code have to run 3 times of the same function and send the limit number by multiplying it. But somehow runRequest's num variable never reaches the 3, firebug console shows num as 1 or sometimes 2 and it repeats infinite. How to avoid it and make it run only 3 syncronised calls?

Comment: I don't think so that the "ajaxComplete" method must be declare into your "success" callback : it is redondant with the current callback. Just try to comment this line and let us know how it works

Comment: you mean should i comment the ajaxcomplete method? like this //$("#console").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)

Comment: Yes, the fact is that you declare a new handler each time you reach the success callback. It could generate some problem.

Comment: God I love you!, how could this happen? is it a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, a mis-use of the api. See my answer for a fuller explanation . (and props to Bouillou for a beating me to the punch :-) )

Comment: No, check the JQuery doc : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/, the ajaxComplete method is called each time that a success AJAX callback is fired. You must use the success callback OR use the ajaxComplete to call your function, but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is your use of `.ajaxComplete()`. According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), it is a separate event handler registration method. In other words, your success function is registering an event to fire upon the next completion. I think this would also cause your first data set to be thrown away.

An additional note, you're using the `data` parameter to pass in data. This is supposed to be an object, not a query string. If you use a GET Ajax call, it gets converted to a query string. `url: "?type="+type+"&page="+num*1000,` and `data: { "type": type, "page": num*1000 }` are equivalent.

Try rewriting it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    url: "#",
    async: false,
    data: { "type": type, "page": num*1000 },
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#console").append(msg);
        runRequest(num+1);
    });
}
```

The `.ajaxComplete()` method is more for the purpose of inserting a separate function call or behavior into every ajax success handler (when you have many such requests on the same page and want each of them to append to the console, in addition to doing their normal callback). Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#console").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
    {
        // $(this) is pointing to the #console ID because the function is bound to it
        $(this).append('Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is ' +
                 xhr.responseHTML);
        runRequest(num+1);
    });
    // variables

    // document event bindings/handlers

    // Ajax functions (you could move this outside of the .ready function

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/foo/?bar=' + i,
        ajaxI: i,
        success: function(widgets) {
            x = this.ajaxI; // now you can use x instead of i

            // ...
        }
    });
}
```