# How to put ajax inside a loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request within an ajax request that is inside a loop. Here it is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input_files.length; i++) {
 $.ajaxFileUpload({
  url : dasdasdsa,
  success : function () {
    $.ajax({
    var get_the_number_in_the_last_of_array = input_files[i].split('_').pop();
    });
  }
 });

}
```

putting `async: false` doesnt work. How to go around this? What i want is that every loop the inner ajax gets the right variable `i`. What happens in my code is that the inner ajax always gets the last `i`.

Note: variable `input_files` is an array containing ids, example "my_id_number_9". That 9 in the last is what i want to get in the split.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332854/jquery-ajax-in-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `closure` to pass the correct value of `i` -

```
for (var i = 0; i < input_files.length; i++) {

    (function (index) {
        $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url : dasdasdsa,
            success : function () {

                $.ajax({
                    var get_the_number_in_the_last_of_array = input_files[index]
                        .split('_').pop();
                });
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Where does the 'index' came from? is it the catcher variable for `i`?

Comment: @BelmarkCaday: `index` is a parameter to the anonymous function that I've defined, which is also immediately being invoked, and passed `i` as the argument. In this way, you are passing the value of `i` in every iteration to the anonymous function, which will be used in the `success` callback. Otherwise, a reference to the `i` will be captured by the callback, which will cause it to always use the last value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now. And it also solved my 2 weeks problem now. Thanks sir. You are a genius

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the usage of closure variable `i` inside a async callback method.

Since `input_files` is an array you can fix it easily using $.each() to iterate

```
$.each(input_files, function (idx, file) {
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: dasdasdsa,
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                var get_the_number_in_the_last_of_array = file.split('_').pop();
                //or var get_the_number_in_the_last_of_array = input_files[idx].split('_').pop();
            });
        }
    });
})
```

The problem... inside the ajax callback method the variable `i` is used which is declared in the outer closure scope so all the ajax request callback methods share the same instance of `i`. Now what happens is since the request is asynchronous the loop is finished before the callback is executed so when the callbacks are executed `i` will be equal to `input_files` which will result in `input_files[idx]` giving undefined as the value

The proposed solution will create a private closure for each iteration of the loop which will preserve values of variable declared within the closure from being modified other loops.

Comment: How does it differ from for loop? how does it solve my problem on ajax's async issue. *assuming this is an ajax async issue*

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation sir, I understand it now. So that is what closures are all about. Thanks a lot, really really thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try closure function

```
for (var i = 0; i < input_files.length; i++) {
(function(i)
{
 $.ajaxFileUpload({
  url : dasdasdsa,
  success : function () {
    $.ajax({
    var get_the_number_in_the_last_of_array = input_files[i].split('_').pop();
    });
  }
 });
})(i);

}
```